# Passing a value from JSON to be a variable for a dynamic search link in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## Question

In a vuejs project, how should i pass a value that I am getting form a JSON file into a value for a link? specifically a search link.

I realize there are many ways to do this using other libraries or plain javascript, but wondering if there is a suggested way for vuejs, otherwise plain ES6 would be fine

---

### Background

In my conditional if a recipe is not in the host database, a link is shown to "find similar recipes". Since I will always have a name but not a recipe, i can at least say something like "click link for recipes similar to [Braised Duck](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=braised+duck&t=h_&ia=recipes) taco"

A hard coded url would be

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=braised+duck&t=h_&ia=recipes
```

but for my link i need to take the name of the taco and pass that into query

#### JS - Babel

```
function otherTaco (str) {
  const recipeQuery 
  return {}
}
```

#### JSON - sample value

```
"name":"Pepper Tempeh"
```

#### HTML

```
<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=taco&t=h_&ia=web" target="_blank"> {{ taco.name }}</a>
```

The "taco" in this part should instead be the value of the taco.name `?q=taco&t=h_&ia=web"`

Working demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the JSON input? All you want is to get the recipe's name and replace it on the query?

Comment: @FelipeLanza of course, i updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
<a :href="'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + taco.name + '&t=h_&ia=web'" target="_blank"> {{ taco.name }}</a>
```

When you v-bind to a tag attribute, you can then treat it like a javascript expression.

Comment: Wow that was exactly what i needed